# MySQL - insert same + consecutive value between A and B or specifically (422,583)

Tags: mysql

Suppose you need to insert a bunch of values including row values that are consecutive between A and B (Say 422 and 583)

```
(note, id column as primary key auto-incrementing not shown here)
id_ext, bpm 
422, 130
423, 130
424, 130
425, 130
```

Column 1 is consecutive between A and B 
Column 2 is always the same

How do you write an elegant mysql statement for this?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Comment: Hmm which version allows the best implementation?

Comment: MySQL 8+ would allow you to use a CTE which would make this much simpler.

Comment: Provide both solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8+ you can use a CTE to generate the required list of numbers to insert into the table:

```
insert test
with recursive cte as (
    select 422 as id_ext, 130 as bpm
    union all
    select id_ext + 1, bpm
    from cte where id_ext < 425
)
select *
from cte
```

In MySQL 5.7 and below, you need to use a numbers table, which you can create on the fly using the following query:

```
insert into test
select id_ext, 130
from (select n100.n*100 + n10.n*10 + n.n AS id_ext
      from (select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
             union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
             union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) n
      cross join (select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
             union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
             union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) n10
      cross join (select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3
             union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
             union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) n100
      ) e
where id_ext between 428 and 431
```

[Demo (of both queries) on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=61e3049ab7c7280938725c081c4e5916)

You would need to adjust the numbers in the CTE and the `WHERE` clause to suit your requirements.

Comment: Did this answer your question? If not, could you provide more information to help answer it?